# feathers-mongoose error: 'You must provide a Mongoose Model'

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, feathersjs

I'm trying out feathersjs and I want to use mongoose to connect and interact with mongodb. I've created a simple model, `message.js`, which I require in my `app.js`. But when I run my app I get this error followed by a crash:

```
C:\Users\someuser\development\myapp\node_modules\feathers-mongoose\lib\service.js:17
      throw new Error('You must provide a Mongoose Model');
      ^

Error: You must provide a Mongoose Model
    at new Service (C:\Users\someuser\development\myapp\node_modules\feathers-mongoose\lib\service.js:17:13)
    at init (C:\Users\someuser\development\myapp\node_modules\feathers-mongoose\lib\service.js:326:10)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\someuser\development\myapp\app.js:61:22)
    at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:693:10)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:191:16)
    at bootstrap_node.js:612:3
```

This is what my model looks like:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var messageSchema = new Schema({
    text:  String,
    author: String,
    date: { type: Date, default: Date.now }
});

var Message = mongoose.model('Message', messageSchema);
module.exports = Message;
```

And in my `app.js`:

```
const MessageModel = require('./models/message');
```

I logged what is being stored inside the MessageModel and got:

```
Model: {"_id":"5b8936062f2e201d1852179e","date":"2018-08-31T12:35:18.499Z"}
```

I've tried searching for the issue but I can't really find anything useful, and as far as I know, there is nothing wrong with my model.

Comment: I tested your code, `console.log(MessageModel)` prints the whole `model` actually unlike in your case where it is printing a document I believe. Are you sure that you do not have another variable by same name as model.

Comment: No, not that I've created at least. I don't know if feathers does something behind the scenes that could cause this?

Answer (score 1):

RIGHT: You have to register your service like this:

```
const MessageModel = require('./models/message');    
app.use('/messages', service({
      Model: MessageModel
    }));
```

In the Examples they call the MessageModel just Model:

```
const Model = require('./models/message');
```

So they can do this:

```
app.use('/messages', service({
  Model
}));
```

Its the same like:

```
app.use('/messages', service({
  Model: Model
}));
```

WRONG: You probably register your service like this:

```
app.use('/messages', service({
  MessageModel
}));
```